# What technique should I think about when I have to transform an algorithm from O(n) to O(1) space complexity?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, space, space-complexity

For example for the Build Array from Permutation (LeetCode question).
I was thinking about temporary variable to transform this brut fore algorithm from O(n) to O(1)space complexity algorithm. (solutions are from [dev.to](https://dev.to/vishnureddys/build-array-from-permutation-solution-to-leetcode-problem-357l)).

A brut force algorithm.

```
class Solution:
def buildArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    res = []
    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        res.append(nums[nums[i]])
    return res
```

I couldn't find a solution using a temporary variable.
Instead, I found that people did this:

O(1) space complexity algorithm.

```
class Solution:
def buildArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    n = len(nums)
    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        nums[i]=nums[i]+(n*(nums[nums[i]]%n))

    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        nums[i] = int(nums[i]/n)

    return nums
```

My question, to what technique should I think about when I have to transform an algorithm from O(n) to O(1) space complexity?

Comment: There isn't any "technique" for this. You've got to focus on the given properties of the input statement to break down the problem into subproblems and effectively solve them

Comment: Using "spare bits" in the input array is not really O(1) space. The new numbers in the list each need around 2log_2(n) bits to store, whereas the original numbers in the list need around log_2(n) bits. That's because the original numbers were in the range 0 to n, and the new numbers 0 to n^2. Those extra bits mean additional allocations in general.

Answer (score 2):

If an algorithm takes up `O(n)` space, then it must be using the space for some purpose; usually for computing some value that you can readily look up later. This will usually lead to better time complexity. If you give up on space, say make `O(n)` to `O(1)`, you may have to settle for a higher time complexity.

Consider [prefix sum algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum). It takes `O(n)` space, but then I can answer subsequent queries in `O(1)`. If I do not want to use `O(n)` space, then queries will take `O(n)`. So, it is a trade-off between time and space complexity.